# How to define pressing Ctrl twice as a keyboard shortcut in Ubuntu

Tags: keyboard, shortcut-keys

I'd like to be able to map a double press on the ctrl key to a keyboard shortcut that other applications can use.

Example use case,

- Visual studio code I double press shift twice to bring up global find window

I found this old post [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/395259/how-to-define-pressing-ctrl-twice-as-a-keyboard-shortcut-in-linux-to-launch-a-c) but looking for something a bit easier.

Any ideas?

Comment: This isn't really an answer (so I'm leaving it as a comment), but if you happen to have a keyboard running [QMK](https://qmk.fm/), this is really easy to do using [Tap Dance](https://docs.qmk.fm/#/feature_tap_dance).

Comment: unlikely, dell xps

Comment: Yeah, laptop keyboards, as far as I know, never do anything that fancy.